# JavaScript Resize iFrame - working in Firefox/IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Against my better judgement I've been forced into using an iframe to deliver HTML5 content via a CMS which can't manage the content by itself. The iframe and host page are on the same domain so I can communicate between them fairly readily.

The content in the iFrame dynamically resizes (it's an online payment page and has confirmation details/error messages for fields improperly filled in) and I'm using this JavaScript to resize it:

```
function autoResize(id){
  var newheight;
  var newwidth;

  if(document.getElementById){
      newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
      newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
  }

      document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
      document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
 }
```

I'm using this code to display the iframe in the host page, the height is the maximum size the iframe page can reach:

```
 <iframe id="iframe1" height="1550px" frameborder="0" width="100% marginheight="0" src="/something.html" scrolling="no" onload="autoResize('iframe1')"/>
```

To dynamically resize the page elements and for scrolling I'm using onclick events in the iframe code which communicate with the parent page:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function(){parent.parent.autoResize('iframe1');},10); window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,500);"
```

The setTimeout is required because I have other scripts which run on the onclick events and I need them to fire first and resize the iframe page THEN tell the host page to resize the iframe.

This is working much better than I expected in Firefox and IE11 but it's not working in Chrome. Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this functionality working in Chrome?

I'm assuming it's just a few tweaks specific to Chrome but it's 8:45am and I've been working on it since 9pm last night so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks,

Mike

Oh, credit where credit is due. I got the original resize code (first quoted block) from a StackOverflow post. I just forgot to bookmark the link!

Comment: Added a missing close quotes (wasn't missing in the code - just on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing double quote in your iframe
that's the correction

```
<iframe id="iframe1" height="1550px" frameborder="0" width="100%"    marginheight="0" src="/something.html" scrolling="no" onload="autoResize('iframe1')>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I actually typed that out rather than copy pasting. The double quote is in place on the code it's just not firing. It doesn't fire on both page load or page clicks on buttons with the onclick event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out though, I've updated my original post to reflect it